# list with scrollview

Tags: java, android

I have list with `scrollview` after i add the scroll i try to change the height
of the scroll view so the list be in the center of the layout and the height be more but it dose not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` is scrollable. You can't put `ListView` inside of `ScrollView`.

Try this sample of code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg_all_1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/top_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    layout="@layout/layout_header" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_menu"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    layout="@layout/layout_footer" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Oh my, you are right. I'm sorry. But it is scrollable and it doesn't work properly inside ScrollView ^^'

Comment: really are you sure ? amd what about the  height where i can change it ? told me what should i do :(

Comment: @ blackbelt so what should i do ?

Comment: Set id for your footer, delete ScrollView and set inside ListView android:above="@+id/your_footer_id". It should help. Btw you don't need this RelativeLayout in which ListView is either.

Comment: @AgataSworowska i is just change the place without change the height